# i cant do send a announce whit strophe.js, what are modules it is necessary?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd-module, strophe.js

i cant do send a announce whit strophe from ejabberd sever 18.03. 
It is possible, how?
i cant use this code ?
https://github.com/bbc/Strophejs-PubSub-Demo/blob/master/js/publisher.js

Answer (score 0):

If user1@localhost is an account with admin rights in ejabberd configuration, then you can execute this command to send an announcement message to all the users in localhost:

> $ ejabberdctl send_message chat user1@localhost localhost/announce/all "" "Message to all"

Comment: It is possible send this message in javascript?